# Express Middleware to enable access-control-allow-origin for GET, PUT, POST, DELETE required

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I have implemented Nodejs REST API for my website and using Reactjs for web and React Native for mobile app. I had implemented CORS using the following code:

```
app.options('/*', (_req, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Endpoint, Token');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

It was doing fine for the mobile app but now when I am implemented the web I need to add middle-wares enabling CORS for each request method, like so:

```
app.get('/*', (_req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, Endpoint, Token');
    next();
});
```

The browser would give exception if I don't do like above. I knew about the OPTIONS pre-flight request and so I had added the CORS enabling middle-ware but, now, as I have to add middle-wares for methods of subsequent requests, I can't find any explanation why the previous approach stopped working for the requests following the pre-flight. I haven't retested the mobile app, though, but I can tell that the request headers are the same as the previous one. Can anybody explain what's happening?

Comment: Did you try this?  `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')`

Comment: Oh and I would recomend you using package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors if you want

Comment: I have already mentioned `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'`. Actually I didn't want to use any package for such a small thing. May be I would consider using it in future if the situation demands.

Comment: I just needed an explanation about it because the code is already working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Express I'd suggest `app.use()` to handle all routes and methods:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => { 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
    ...   

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).send('Go away');        
    } else next();   
});
```

Comment: I still can't get to explain that why the middle-ware for "Options" request method was working alone and requests were blocked by the client on the basis of header and why now I have to add headers for all the incoming requests.

Comment: Apparently your browser sends the requests slightly different than your mobile app. Try looking there for differences. Also, maybe `"/*"` is unnecessary? Should work without it. Also in my app I use slighltly different Allow-Headers line: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Accept');`. You can try it out.

Comment: Yeah apparently that's what's happening. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yeah, I have molded the headers according to my needs :) Also the "/*" is unnecessary, you are right. But so far I remember it was not working that way, may be something was missing. I will give it a try again.